# CSS - Enabling transition for only one axis (Y)

Tags: javascript, css

How to set a transition only for the y axis?

There's a `<div>` that have to moves on window resize with JavaScript (JS), but it have to moves with transition only over the Y axis and resize instantly when the resize it's on the X axis.

Setting it like

```
---------------------------------------------
|                 Window                    |
--------------------------------------------
| .efnkerf  |                  .erifnrekf   |
--------------------------------------------
//CSS
div.erifnrekf {
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
//JS (JQuery)
$(window).on('resize',function(e){
    w = $(window).innerWidth() - $(".efnkerf").outerWidth(true);
    $(".erifnrekf").css('max-width',w);
});
```

does not give the desired results because the transition happens on each axis.

Comment: Please show the function that sets the Y of the div

Comment: @Arleigh Hix *Please show the function that sets the Y of the div*. You comment request it's satisfied

Comment: Just change `all` to `height` read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: @Arleigh Hix *Just change all to height read this: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition* I don't have to read nothing more. Perfect. It's what i need. TNX.

Comment: No, you do need to read more, and before asking here.

Comment: @Arleigh Hix *Just change all to height read this: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition* The sense it's I don't have to read nothing more, I've already read. An other time: Just what i need. Here lets go. TNX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TNX to @Arleigh Hix.

The definitive solution it's.

```
//CSS
div.erifnrekf {
    -webkit-transition: height .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height .6s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height .6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height .6s ease-in-out;
    transition: height .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

Good work